# LIBAV - avprobe

Tags: libav, avprobe

Coming from a linux background. I was just wondering that the best way to install avprobe on OSX is?

I tried installing libav: http://libav.org/download.html but this seems to use avconf. I have a script that was written by someone else that depends on avprobe being executed directly.

Google doesn't really help. I need to be able to run avprobe directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 29):

`brew install libav` will provide you `avconv` and `avprobe`.

Comment: Is it really that easy on OSX? I can't even figure out how to get it done on Windows, but I'm guessing it's not three words in a command line, whatever it is.

Comment: Did all of that God knows how many times, tried both main and nightly release versions, added the folder it was located in to the PATH environment variable, but still never managed to get it recognised by `youtube-dl`, the program I was trying to use it with.

Answer (score -2):

I think you downloaded the wrong thing. Libav is intended to be baked into software and doesn't really have standalone executables. A related project to libav (related in that they forked a while back) is ffmpeg.

The package you want is ffmpeg, avprobe comes with it.

You can download precompiled OSX binaries here, http://ffmpegmac.net/ or compile them yourself from here http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#releases